# Anyone can submit without logging in

Tags: php, html, mysql

Everyone can save info without login, what am I doing wrong? There is also `session.php`, but it does not work.

```php
<?php
    include('session.php');
?>
<form name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input value="" name="username" id="username" hidden>
    <input value="" name="nam" id="nam" placeholder="Contact Name" type="text" >
    <input value="" name="no" id="no" placeholder="Contact Number" type="text" >
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Store Contact">
</form>
<?php
    $dbhost = 'host';
    $dbuser = 'user';
    $dbpass = 'pass';
    $conn   = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO xyz (username, nam, no) VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[nam]','$_POST[no]')";

        mysql_select_db('db');
        $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
        if (!$retval) {
            die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "<span>Contact Stored...  :)</span>\n";
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Post your session.php code.

Comment: Obligatory comment about `mysql_*`-functions being deprecated, you should convert to `mysqli` or `PDO` to avoid SQL-injection!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
 $dbhost = 'host';
 $dbuser = 'user';
 $dbpass = 'pass';
```

add `session_start();` after `<?php` or session something like that from your session.php

Comment: its working...by the way

Comment: If you add `session_start` after the `<?php` pointed (line 10), you'll get an error like "headers already sent by..." because the HTML for `form` is already printed to the output (so there had to be a header saying "200 OK" in the HTTP request at that level). Nevertheless you SHOULD `session_start" after the first `<?php` which is why I thought there was a `include('session.php');`

Answer (score 3):

There is a huge problem with your code !!
You start your

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

with the `INSERT`command to your database before even checking what was submitted.

you should start with checking against any wrong input before. And even before that, you should `sanitize` your POST data because using it directly in your query is a spectacular security risk. You should realize that newbie hacker kids regularly search for random websites with this kind of breach to train their early skills.

I'll let you search for informations about [Sanitizing $_POST](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) and [Filter input array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_input_array.asp), but for your problem you simply have to check

```
if (empty($_POST['username']))
```

or maybe you want a minimum number of characters ? only letters and spaces ? Ideally, you'd search about [Regular Expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm) but with an explicit Google Search you could find them all ready to use.

Then of course you don't want people with the same username so maybe you'd go for a

```
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT username
    FROM users
    WHERE username = '".$sanitized_post['username']."';
");
```

then check if

```
(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
```

before throwing your `INSERT INTO` query